# Enclosing points in rectangles.

Tags: geometry

Given N points(x,y). 
How can we enclose M points in two rectangles such that each rectangle contains M/2 points and sum of the perimeter of two rectangles is minimum? I need to find such perimeter only.

Given M<=N/2, X,Y<=250, N<=5000.

I know the minimum bounding box to enclose k points but how to incorporate it for two box(rectangle).

[Refer to image for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih0lY.png)

Comment: Do we have some reason to think there would be an algorithm that is always better than "brute force" trial and error? Perhaps it would help if you  explain more about where this problem came from and why you need to solve it.

Comment: Yes there would be an algorithm better than brute force. We can enclose M points in a single rectangle using minimum box bounding and divide it into two rectangles having M/2 points each.

Comment: This is an assignment problem from my competitive programming chapter of my college.

Comment: Good luck in your competition, then.

Comment: You can only consider the rectangles whose edges coincides with the grid?

Comment: No, we can consider any rectangle.